# Can't create a virtual environment in command prompt for python

Tags: python, virtualenv

I was trying to create a new virtual environment in command prompt, but it is showing 'virtualenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

im having python 3.10

when i try to install virtual env it shows 'Requirement is already satisfied'[cmd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hl2TO.png)

Comment: Is Python on your Path? In your terminal, enter `echo %path% | find /i "python"` - if it returns a value, make sure the `%path%` includes "C:\Program Files\Python310\Scripts\" (or wherever you Python is installed, but it's likely there). Also, I think you need to use `venv` and not `virtualenv`

Comment: ;C:\Program Files\Python310\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Python310\;  it is there (2 times) and i tried venv no luck

Comment: What happens if you use `venv` instead? That works for me on Windows.

Comment: If you installed it via `pip`, then I believe you will have to run it as a python module. Example: `python -m virtualenv my_env`.  I personallly just use `venv` so maybe someone with more `virtualenv` experience can confirm

Comment: it is working when using "python -m virtualenv my_env"  what was i doing wrong in the previous commands, why was it not working with those commands

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+is+not+recognized+as+an+internal+or+external+command

Comment: @Amalkrishna that command was nowhere in your path.

Comment: how to add that to path?

Comment: and What is the difference between using `virtualenv` ,   `venv` , `mkvritualenv`